# Code within dispatch_barrier_async not executing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I tried out a simple example to learn to use dispatch-barrier async.  Basically, a single-view iOS app with ViewDidLoad as below.  Three tasks are submitted to a concurrent queue.  Two of them read a variable while third writes to the variable.

I am seeing that the write never gets executed (i.e X = X + 10 never gets executed.)  If I just submit it using dispatch_async (instead of protecting it in a dispatch_barrier_async) as shown in the last piece code, it works.  (Surprisingly there is no issue of writing to X at the same time of 2 reads of X even when I don't protect it using disaptch_barrier_async).

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue;

__block int X = 10;

backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.smarthome.readwriteQ", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    while (1) {
        NSLog(@"Task 1: X = %d",X);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:4];
    }
});

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    while (1) {
        NSLog(@"Task 2: X = %d",X);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:4];
    }
});

//This does not work
dispatch_barrier_async(backgroundQueue,^(void){
    while (1) {
        X = X + 10;
        NSLog(@"Task 3: After Writing X = %d",X);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
    }
 });

 //This works
 dispatch_async(backgroundQueue,^(void){
    while (1) {
        X = X + 10;
        NSLog(@"Task 3: After Writing X = %d",X);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
    }
 });
}
```

I guess I have not understood dispatch_barrier_async correctly.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW67) says:

> When it encounters a barrier, a concurrent queue delays the execution of the barrier block (or any further blocks) until all blocks submitted before the barrier finish executing.

You submitted two blocks that will *never* finish executing, and then submitted the barrier block. So GCD never executes the barrier block.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.

Comment: Does this mean that if I have a few long running tasks and each of them reads or modifies a shared variable, then I need at least two dispatch queues: one or more queue that runs the tasks and then one queue that is used to submit tasks that read or write the shared variable?

Comment: That might make sense, sure.